# How can I check for socket connection after window is shown?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi

I've followed a tutorial on youtube on win32 socket programming. It worked good until I tried implementing win32 winapi application and now when I click on Debug (to run the app), no application runs.

```
#include "Resource.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

void AppendText(const HWND &hwnd, TCHAR *newText) {
    HWND hwndOutput = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_OUTPUT);
    int outLength = GetWindowTextLength(hwndOutput) + lstrlen(newText) + 1;
    TCHAR * buf = (TCHAR *)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, outLength * sizeof(TCHAR));
    if (!buf) return;
    GetWindowText(hwndOutput, buf, outLength);
    _tcscat_s(buf, outLength, newText);
    SetWindowText(hwndOutput, buf);
    GlobalFree(buf);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MsgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
                      HWND hServEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 10, 10, 370, 150, hwnd, (HMENU)MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_OUTPUT), NULL, NULL);

                      WSADATA wsa;
                      WORD Version = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
                      WSAStartup(Version, &wsa);

                      SOCKET Listen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
                      SOCKET Connect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
                      SOCKADDR_IN Server;

                      Server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
                      Server.sin_family = AF_INET;
                      Server.sin_port = htons(100);

                      bind(Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, sizeof(Server));
                      listen(Listen, 1);

                      int size = sizeof(Server);
                      AppendText(hwnd, "Listening..\r\n");

                      for (;;) {
                          if (Connect = accept(Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &size)) {
                              AppendText(hwnd, "Connection was reached\r\n");
                              break;
                          }
                      }
                      WSACleanup();
                      return 0;
    }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MsgProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = "Main_Window";
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.style = 0;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to register window class.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "Main_Window", "Server", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 200, 100, 400, 200, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hwnd) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to create window.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(msg));

    while (msg.message != WM_QUIT) {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code in the WM_CREATE case, below the edit control creation is all copy and pasted from the tutorial I watched, and works. But when I implemented everything else, it doesn't work. I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013 Express. Anybody know why this won't work?

Comment: Well I decided to comment stuff out to see if I could Identify the problem, and its within the for loop in WM_CREATE. I'm assuming that its checking for a connection before the window is shown. How can i fix that problem?

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to be more specific. "Trouble with win32 socket programming" contains no information about the actual problem, and will not have much value to future readers finding it in a search result. We know from the tags that it's about Windows sockets and that you're using C++, so the gist of what remains in your title is "trouble with programming", and that conveys no information. Being more specific about the actual problem will help you get answers more quickly as well. Thanks.

Comment: The first message sent to a window **after** it is displayed is [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632652.aspx). You can move your code to this message handler, if you must ensure that the window is displayed prior to establishing a connection.

Comment: Don't execute network code in the event thread. Start a separate thread.

Comment: @EJP: [Windows Sockets 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673.aspx) offer an event based API (see [Overlapped I/O and Event Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740087.aspx)) that is very well prepared to run on the GUI thread.

Comment: Why a non-blocking PeekMessage() loop?  You need to warm up your office?

Comment: Also, like @EJP says, the GUI thread is for doing GUI work and is best not used for network handling.

Comment: @MartinJames That is how Chili does it in his C++ / DirectX Game programming tutorials so that's how I started doing it.

Comment: This is my first networking C++ project that I'm doing.